# Run R markdown (.Rmd) from inside other R script to produce HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

As the example, if you create a new R markdown file and save it as 'test'.  Can one then run or deploy this test.Rmd file from within a normal R script.  The purpose being to generate the output in HTML, without having to open the .Rmd file.

I'm hoping to create one master file to do this for many markdown files in one go; which would save considerable time as you then don't have to open many markdown files and wait for each one to complete.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for `rmarkdown::render()`.

## Contents of "test.Rmd"

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

## Contents of script.R

```
# provided test.Rmd is in the working directory
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")
```

## A Way to Render Multiple Rmd

```
cwd_rmd_files <- list.files(pattern = ".Rmd$")
lapply(cwd_rmd_files, rmarkdown::render)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [the-mad-statter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9393213/the-mad-statter), your answer was very helpful. The issue I faced, required me to prepare markdown dynamically. By adapting your code, that's easily possible:

## Contents of "test_dyn.rmd"

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

The chunk below adds formatted text, based on your inputs.
```{r text, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
cat(text)
```

The chunk below uses your input in as code.
```{r results}
y
```
````

## Contents of "script_dyn.r"

```
in_text <- c("**Test 1**", "*Test 2*")
in_y <- 1:2

lapply(1:2, function(x) {
  text <- in_text[[x]]
  y <- in_y[[x]]
  rmarkdown::render(input = "test_dyn.rmd", output_file = paste0("test", x))
})
```

Like this you can create files with different text and different variables values in your code.

Comment: Interesting to know the render environment can find your y values. I thought rendering occurred in a new environment, but apparently that is only true for knitting. If you want to pass in data to an RMarkdown document you might consider [parameterized reporting](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html).

Comment: Thanks, that seems handy!

Comment: Is there a way to run the R code without the overhead of rendering/knitting? For instance, the R code could be extracted from the Rmd and executed.